# Android ActionBar: show/hide tabs dynamically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

Is it possible to remove/restore the tab bar from the action bar dynamically?

Up to now I did this by changing the navigation mode of the action bar. I used following code to remove and restore the tab bar:

```
@Override 
public void restoreTabs() {     
    getSupportActionBar()
    .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}

@Override
public void removeTabs() {      
    getSupportActionBar()
    .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    this.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

That works, but there is a big problem: Everytime I call `setNavigationMode`, `onTabSelected` is called in the `TabListener` and the currently opend tab gets recreated.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the actionbar tabs dynamically, you simply need:

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

To add them on the fly, simply do:

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

For the second case, the assumption is that after setting the navigation mode, you will also add tabs, to the action bar, similar to this:

```
for (int resourceId : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(resourceId)
                .setTabListener(this));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended, since the tab is being selected because it was not appearing.
I suggest you to do by your own the control in TabListener.