# Navigation drawer with tabs in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs, navigation

I am making an android app . I am using navigation drawer and some of the fragments which i am inflating using navigation drawer contain tab layout and some are normal fragments with textview .

I am facing 2 issues that when

1. i am opening the navigation drawer item with tabs afterthat its automatically keeping those tabs in the view even for the fragments that are not with tabs.
2. When i am opening the fragment with tabs 2nd time or more . Its duplicating the tabs. I mean if the first time no of tabs are 3 then the next time when i open the fragment the no. of tabs get doubled.

Activity with navigation drawer

```
public class MainFeedActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mDrawertitles;
LinearLayout drawerll;
String username;
TextView t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainfeed);

    username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username").toString();

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_uname_tv);
    t.setText(username);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawertitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    drawerll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerll);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawertitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(2);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return true;

}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    if (position == 0) {

        Fragment fragment = new Home();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);
    }

    else if (position == 1) {

        Fragment fragment = new Statistics();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);

    } else {
        Fragment fragment = new Help();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerll);

    }
}

/*
 * 
 * protected boolean isOnline() { ConnectivityManager cm =
 * (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 * NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); if (netInfo != null &&
 * netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) { return true; } else { return false;
 * } }
 */

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.

    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
```

}

Fragments

```
  public class Home extends Fragment {

ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3;
Fragment fragmentTab1 = new Connected();
Fragment fragmentTab2 = new Disconnected();
Fragment fragmentTab3 = new AllDevices();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    // Hide Actionbar Title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
    Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3");

    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
    Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab3);

    return view;
}
```

}

Fragments:

```
public class Help  extends Fragment {


Button b;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.help, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: when position!= 1, you need to change the actionBar Navigation Mode....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298930/android-actionbar-show-hide-tabs-dynamically

Comment: Thanks @RafiduzzamanSonnet , 1st problem is solved

Comment: Could you suggest solution for 2nd problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution of my problems:

1. 1st problem solved with the help of denvercoder9

when position!= 1, you need to change the actionBar Navigation Mode.... [Android ActionBar: show/hide tabs dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298930) – denvercoder9

2. 2nd problem's solution is
   I need to use this

ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

```
    actionBar.removeAllTabs();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

in Home.java class

This resolved the problem of tabs duplication.

Thanks Stackoverflow for helping me :)

Comment: Hi @rahul-saxena i have the same issue (issue 1) but i use TabLayout instead of ActionBar. can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue so the solution is simple.

Ans 1: If you don't want Tabs in specific fragment then you can set the navigation bar as

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

Ans 2: Either remove the tabs from the home fragment each time u select it or u can check if required tabs already present there then dont add any more tabs in it like this

```
int tabCount= actionBar.getTabCount();

if(tabCount!=3){
Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");
    Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab3");

    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));
    Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab3));

    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
}
return view;
```

Hope it will solve your problem